# External file (images, sounds) naming convention at Xcode

Tags: naming, svn, xcode, conventions

- What is better naming conventions at Xcode regardng External File
  (images, sounds) etc?
- Is there any guideline from vendor Apple?
- As we store our projects at SVN, is there any complicity from Hosted
  Server (we use Linux + Server SVN ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to follow Unix naming conventions here

- Always use lowercase characters
- Only 1 dot for file extension, otherwise no dot allowed
- No white space allowed
- For long file name use hyphen(-)

If you follow Unix naming conventions, there will no complexity as your server configuration.